# Is there a way to return a value from function after redirect() in Flask?

Tags: python, html, if-statement, flask, jinja2

Here I am sharing an example code of what i am trying to achieve.

```
my_bluprint = Blueprint('index',
                   __name__,
                   template_folder=template_dir)

@my_bluprint.route('/print', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def my_function_2():
    print('i was redirected')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        age = request.form.get('age')
        print('AGE: ', age)

    return render_template("form2.html")

@my_bluprint.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def my_function():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('my_function')
        # do something
        name = request.form.get('name')
        print('my_name', name)
        if name == 'root':
            print('name is ', name)
            return redirect(url_for("index.my_function_2"))
        # age = request.form.get('age')
        print('AGE: ',age) # I need input age from my_function_2 here
        age_trans = my_module.ageMul(age)
        print('TransAGE: ', age_trans)
        return render_template("result.html", result=age_trans)
    return render_template("form1.html")
```

I need to render different templates depending on the input from previous template. 
On run time my program will use the input from one template to decide which template to redirect next. I tried rendering the templates the way i have used in my example code but I need inputs from previous templates for further processing combined with inputs of all the other templates which were rendered. 
**EDIT**
i am able to redirect to other routes in my code. but i need input from the template i am using in `my_function_2()` in `my_function()` after the execution of `my_function_2()`. which means i need to come back to main route i-e `/test` with data from `my_function_2`. I need help in understanding how can I do that
**Another Idea**

is there a way to render different templates using conditions in same function lets say `my_function()`. If input from one html form makes the condition true render template A else render template B ? meanwhile retaining the inputs from first template rendered in `my_function()`? in this way i can have only one route rendering multiple templates ? but i want to keep data from all the templates previously rendered

**what would be the good approach of doing this ?** 
**EIDT 2**
i tried this

```
@my_bluprint.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def my_function():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #name = request.form.get('name')
        session['name'] = request.form['name']
        print('my_name', session['name'])
        if session['name'] == 'root':
            print('name is ', session['name'])
            #return redirect(url_for("index.my_function_2"))
            return render_template("form2.html")
        age = request.form.get('age')
        print('AGE ',age)
        age_trans = my_module.ageMul(age)
        print('TransAGE: ', age_trans)
        print(session['name'])
        return render_template("result.html", result=age_trans)
    return render_template("form1.html")
```

First run goes smooth till `return render_template("form2.html")` after the form submitted here control goes back to `if request.method == 'POST':` and execute it from the start and gives me error here `session['name'] = request.form['name']` but i want to the program control to always move forward with the values it got in first run of `render_template("form1.html")` until the page(url) is refreshed

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what exactly the issues is here. Can you highlight the problem more explicitly?

Comment: @deceze i am able to redirect to other routes in my code. but i need input from the template i am using in `my_function_2()` in `my_function()` after the execution of `my_function_2()'. which means i need to come back to main route i-e `/test` with data from my_function_2. I need help in uderstanding how can I do that?

Comment: These functions represent separate HTTP request handlers. You can only pass information via HTTP. That means, parameters in the URL, or a form and a POST request. Perhaps you can use cookies and/or sessions to store some information too.

Comment: is there a way to render different templates using conditions in same function lets say `my_function()`. If input from one html form makes the condition true render template A else render template B ? meanwhile retaining the inputs from first template rendered in `my_function()`?  in this way i can have only one route rendering multiple templates ? but i want to keep data from all the templates previously rendered.

Comment: Yes, you're already doing that. Simply different `if..else: return render_template(...)`. However, "retaining values" works the same way: the view (template) must have a form or create URLs which contain the values you want to pass on in the next HTTP request. It's all *stateless*. Every time the function is called is like the first time. It won't "retain" anything, it only has the information in the request to work with.

Comment: @deceze can you see the edit 2 ?

Answer (score -1):

You can pass it in query param in redirect or store it in session.

Comment: Yea, there is no redirect there, so? You asked how to pass value from one request handler to another during redirect so that's the answer - pass it as query param or in session.